# Me da error este comando de SQL GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES y no comprendo por qué

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy atascado porque Oracle SQL Developer me da error en este código para asignar todos los privilegios a un usuario y no sé dónde está el error. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias, saludos.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON CADENAS, TECNICOS, TIENDAS TO AGARCIA;
```

En concreto el error que me da es el siguiente:

> ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege
>   00990. 00000 -  "missing or invalid privilege"

Answer (score 2):

En este caso como dice la [Documentacion de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603), los privilegios deben asignarse a la función, uno a la vez.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON CADENAS TO AGARCIA;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TECNICOS TO AGARCIA;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TIENDAS TO AGARCIA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar `GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE`. Creo que usas sintaxis de MySQL :)

```
GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE ON CADENAS, TECNICOS, TIENDAS TO AGARCIA;
```

Recuerda usar un usuario con permisos para hacer ese GRANT.